# Call method from child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using the [FlipClock.js](http://flipclockjs.com/) [Vue Component](https://github.com/mvpleung/vue-flipclock).

My code looks like the code below, and is called from another vue component:

```
import { FlipClock } from '@mvpleung/flipclock';
export default {
  ...
  components: {
    FlipClock
  }
}

...

<flip-clock :options="{clockFace: 'Counter', autoStart: false}" />
```

How can I now manipulate the FlipClock component and for example call the increment method of it?

this.$refs is undefined

Comment: where're you calling `this.$refs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<flip-clock :options="{clockFace: 'Counter', autoStart: false}" />` need to add `ref` attribute like `<flip-clock ref='flipClock' :options="{clockFace: 'Counter', autoStart: false}" />`.

After call `this.$refs.flipClock.increment()`